# How much power can a 3/4 pin fan connector handle?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, fan

I was thinking of buy 5 very high power 120mm fans. These ones to be sepcific.

Delta PFB1212UHE.

These fans require a lot of power. They are 4 amp, 48 watts.

They sell them with the 3 pin connection for motherboard headers. If I was to run these directly off of the board would / could I do any damage to the board?

They also make a version of these with a molex for power and a 3 pin for spin detect.

Just don't want to waste any cash.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The exact motherboard I have is;

ASUS ROG Rampage IV Extreme

My PSU is the Corsair AX760i (760W)

Comment: You would need to check with the board manufacturer (no information supplied) as to whether it can support the **4.8amps** that the fans need.  Being that they draw 48W each I would most likely say that getting the molex version would be a better bet as it draws power directly from the power supply.  Either way you would also need to check the ratings on your PSU as well to ensure that it can push 5 of these fans, both Wattage and Amp ratings, along with your other hardware.

Comment: **The reviews seem to indicate this fan requires a fan controller.**  You are not going to find a motherboard that will support this sort of ampage

Comment: _"They also make a version of these with a molex for power and a 3 pin for spin detect."_ You want that one.